# beautifulsoup: find the n-th element's sibling

Tags: python, find, beautifulsoup, siblings

I have a complex html DOM tree of the following nature:

```
<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- inner most table -->
                        <table>
                            ...
                        </table>

                        <h2>This is hell!</h2>
                    <td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have some logic to find out the inner most table. But after having found it, I need to get the next sibling element (h2). Is there anyway you can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `tag` is the innermost table, then

```
tag.findNextSibling('h2')
```

will be

```
<h2>This is hell!</h2>
```

To literally get the next sibling, you could use `tag.nextSibling`,
which in this case, is `u'\n'`.

If you want the next sibling that is not a NavigableString (such as `u'\n'`), then you could use

```
tag.findNextSibling(text=None)
```

If you want the second sibling (no matter what it is), you could use

```
tag.nextSibling.nextSibling
```

(but note that if `tag` does not have a next sibling, then `tag.nextSibling` will be `None`, and `tag.nextSibling.nextSibling` will raise an `AttributeError`.)

Comment: didnt mean to say find 'h2'...it could be anything. How to get whtever is next...?

Comment: `tag.findNextSibling(text!=u'\n')` is not valid Python. You might have meant `tag.findNextSibling(text=lambda x: not x.isspace())`.

Comment: @Max: Thanks for pointing out my error. `not x.isspace()` unfortunately doesn't work because the `text` keyword argument only applies to NavigableStrings, which the `<h2>...</h2>` tag is not. So, I edited my answer to suggest `text=None` which skips all NavigableStrings.

Answer (score 1):

Every tag object has a [`nextSibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#nextSibling%20and%20previousSibling) attribute that's exactly what you're looking for -- the next sibling (or `None` for a tag that's the last child of its parent tag, of course).